# Problem with asp.net page results

Tags: asp.net, refresh

hey guys,
recently while creating a webpage with a gridview, while binding the gridview with sql database, once when i run the site, it shows me the proper results, but when i make any changes and attempt to run the site again, it does not displays the latest changes, instead it displays the results from the previous cache, but when i clears the history, then when i refresh the page, it shows proper results.

Below is my code which i am using to bind my gridview.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"[connection string goes here]");
public void FillGrid()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select m.ModuleID, md.FriendlyName from Modules m inner join dbo.ModuleDefinitions md on m.ModuleDefID = md.ModuleDefID", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    adap.Fill(dt);
    FunGrid.DataSource = dt;

}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillGrid();
    FunGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Below is the source of the gridview as i am using boundfields to bind gridview.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="FunGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="10">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleId" HeaderText="Module ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FriendlyName" HeaderText="Module Name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the first time i have got some issues like that, Please if anyone guys have came accross such issues please revert back with the resolutions...

Thanks and Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Comment: Perhaps this is a little early but are you at all able to use something like Linq to SQL or EF instead of hardcoding SQL into your app, or is this just for learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable caching for the page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

or add this to your page response:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```